# pyramid.util.Request source code

Tags: python-3.4, pyramid, pylons

I'm new to Python and I am studying Pyramid to learn how to write good code. I wrote this root factory code:

```
class RootFactory(object):
    def __acl__(self):
        return [
            (Allow, 'group:alfa', 'alfa'),
        ]

    def __init__(self, request):
        print(type(request))
        pass
```

and the result shows that "request" is `<class 'pyramid.util.Request'>` but if I open the module pyramid.util.py, to see the source code, I do not found the class Request. I think that this class is in the module `pyramid.request.py`

Could someone explain how this is working?

Comment: Yes. It's `pyramid.request.Request`.  Only reason I can think it could be `pyramid.util.Request` is some sort of import aliasing reason. Might be related to your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

It's an implementation detail of using `config.add_request_method`. When adding request methods, a new class object is created using the `InstancePropertyHelper` which is located in the `pyramid.util` module. This could probably be fixed, but at the end of the day the actual class we care about is `pyramid.request.Request` so you should look there for issues.